# "Ghost" output from locate?

Tags: files, rm, locate

I deleted some files, but they seem to still exist. Can anyone please explain the output of this:

```
m@work:~$ locate cfx.css | xargs rm 
m@work:~$ locate cfx.css
/var/www/wfox/hbr.co.nz/cfx/a/c/cfx.css
/var/www/wfox/modules/gallery/cfx/a/c/cfx.css
/var/www/wfox/phoenix/fp.co.nz/cfx/a/c/cfx.css
/var/www/wfox/tmp.co.nz/cfx/a/c/cfx.css
m@work:~$ cat /var/www/wfox/hbr.co.nz/cfx/a/c/cfx.css
cat: /var/www/wfox/hbr.co.nz/cfx/a/c/cfx.css: No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Run `sudo updatedb` then re-run your locate, expect you'll find it's just that locate's database is not current since you've only just deleted the files concerned.

Comment: by 'as root' I mean simply
`sudo updatedb`